# How can access remote computer in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, remote-access, remote-desktop

I am trying to copy file from my local machine to a remote computer using powershell script.

My Script:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "\\10.10.X.X" -Credential "username\password"
Copy-Item "D:\Test.txt" -Destination "D:\Self Study\" -ToSession $Session
```

And I got below errors:

```
New-PSSession : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri
parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.
At D:\PS_Test_script.ps1:1 char:12
+ $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "\\10.10.17.162" -Credential " ...
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [New-PSSession], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand

Copy-Item : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ToSession'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that
is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At D:\PS_Test_script.ps1:2 char:66
+ ... -Item "D:\Test.txt" -Destination "D:\Self Study\" -ToSession $Session
+                                                                  ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

How can I access the remote computer with a computer name? Is using IP address here is wrong?

Comment: Computer name should not include the \\, just `10.10.17.162`

Comment: You don't need to create a PS session for copying file, you just need to make sure that you have a permission on the destination path. (Copy-Item -Path $localpath -Destination "\\1.1.1.1" -Force) will do it.